# Change variable order in plot_models from sjPlot

Tags: r, sjplot

I want to change the order of which the variables are displayed on the y-axis. Like in this code:

```
mod1 <- lm(mpg ~ cyl + disp + hp, data = mtcars)
mod2 <- lm(drat ~ cyl + disp + hp, data = mtcars)

library(sjPlot)
plot_models(mod1, mod2)
```

How can I for example put hp in the middle between cyl and disp (without changing the formula)? In plot_model, without the s, one can use "order.terms" but this doesn't exist for plot_models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by hacking the data within the plot object.

```r
pp <- plot_models(mod1, mod2)
pp$data <- transform(pp$data, 
    term = factor(term, levels = c("disp", "hp", "cyl")))
print(pp)
```